# what is the difference between stopping and killing process?

Tags: system-monitor

in system monitor you can pause, continue, stop and kill process. first two are clear about what they do but last two seem to do same thing. what does kill do more or less compared to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals)

`SIGKILL`

> The SIGKILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate immediately. In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal.

`SIGSTOP`

> The SIGSTOP signal instructs the operating system to stop a process for later resumption.

Ref. https://superuser.com/questions/594508/whats-the-difference-between-sigkill-and-sigstop

Ref. https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Sending_signal_to_Processes

Comment: Hmmm. If I recall correctly, "stop" executes SIGTERM, and "pause" executes SIGSTOP.